# How convert number to currency vise versa ? (html input/output)

Tags: javascript, html

1). I have tried to make a solution to read string such as '1.120.000' as integer and make calculation with other value.

2). I need to customize user interface to convert string value as currency ?
Exp : '12000' to '12.000'

Note : my country currency using '.' as thousand separator..

Comment: this what I already try : [jsfiddle.net/ch5d22su/](http://jsfiddle.net/ch5d22su/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want two functions. The one should convert the number to string with thousands separation and the other one should convert it back to a regular number.

So here are the functions:

1. *Convert number to string with thousands separation*

```js
function convertToString(number) {
  var string;
  
  // If a number was not passed or passed a non-number then return false
  if (!number || typeof number !== 'number') {
    return false;
  }
    
  // Convert the number to string
  string = number.toString();

  // Reverse the string
  string = string.split('').reverse().join('');

  // Insert dot after every third digit and remove the last dot
  string = string.replace(/(\d{3})/ig, '$1.').replace(/\.$/, '');

  // Reverse back the string
  string = string.split('').reverse().join('');

  return string;
}

// Call example
var number = 1200000;
var string = convertToString(number);
alert(string);
alert('Type of ' + (typeof string));
```

2. *Convert the string back to a number*

```js
function convertToNumber(string) {
  var number;
  
  // If a string was not passed or passed a non-string then return false
  if (!string || typeof string !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Remove the dots
  string = string.replace(/\./ig, '');
  
  // Convert to number. You can also parse to float using parseFloat().
  number = parseInt(string);
  
  // If the string didn't contain a number then return false
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    return false; 
  }
  
  return number;
}

// Call example
var string = '1.200.000';
var number = convertToNumber(string);
alert(number);
alert('Type of ' + (typeof number));
```

If something is not clear for you, please ask me.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELPING ME , ALL ANSWER WAS HELPFUL AND CORRECTLY WITH ALL PARAMETER